# Reading file with python

Tags: python, json, file

this is my code to read a json file . But it doesn't work even the json file is in the same place such as the python file . the error is **'No such file or directory: 'agents-100k.json'** can you help me please

```
import json
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, **agent_attributes):
        for attr_name, attr_value in agent_attributes.items():
            setattr(self, attr_name, attr_value)

def main():
    for agent_attributes in json.load(open("agents-100k.json")):
        agent = Agent(**agent_attributes)
        print(agent.agreeableness)

main()
```

Comment: Use an absolute path to your file and do not rely on relative pathes?

Answer (score 1):

hello it's better to use an absolute path as the above comments say here an example

```
import json
f = open(r'the path of the json file')
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, **agent_attributes):
        for attr_name, attr_value in agent_attributes.items():
            setattr(self, attr_name, attr_value)
def main():
    for agent_attributes in json.load(f):
        agent = Agent(**agent_attributes)
        print(agent.agreeableness)
main()
```